# IPV6 addresses not working on debian 11 - oracle cloud

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipv6

I have an instance in oracle cloud with debian 11

The network configuration for IPV6 is:

```
iface enp0s3 inet6 static
address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
netmask 128
gateway fe80::1
dns-search google.com
dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
accept_ra 0
autoconf 0
privext 0
```

Talking to Oracle support chat, they gave me a link https://www.51sec.org/2021/09/20/enable-ipv6-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure/ to configure ipv6, I clarify that I have already done

ping -6 google.com the result is: Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

ip neigh the result is: fe80::1 dev enp0s3 FAILED

The only difference I found compared to another oracle instance was a line in the network configuration:

```
up ip route replace default via fe80::200:17ff:fecb:ae7f dev enp0s3
```

I don't have that line implemented...

Where do I get the information related to that address?

Is it the same address "fe80::200:17ff:fecb:ae7f" that I must enter or is it another?

ip -6 addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::17ff:fe05:5098/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip -6 route:

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref                                                                                                                                                              medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev enp0s3 metric 1024 onlink pref medium
```

Comment: @larsks I have already posted the information.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that! Reading through too quickly.

Comment: The documentation you linked appears to tell the instance is supposed to be configured dynamically. Using DHCPv6 for CentOS and a mechanism not stated with Ubuntu (and I suppose Debian too then? Could be also DHCPv6, SLAAC or some out of band mechanism?) . But you are configuring it manually. Is there an other link from Oracle for manual configuration or else how did you guess your setting should be the one to use? Anyway to find an IPv6 router: `ping ff02::2%enp0s3` (as it's a link local scope, the interface must be stated).

Comment: @A.B If I type "ping ff02::2%enp0s3" the result is "fe80::17ff:fe01:bbf2" but if I use "up ip route replace default via fe80::17ff:fe01:bbf2 dev enp0s3" it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Then try DHCPv6, reading the documentation you linked I would have used that. I asked an other question in my comment but you didn't answer it. Note that `accept_ra 0` prevents SLAAC.

Comment: And again, asking the same question: why, how, and from where did you get this manual configuration?